# FreeRTOS context switch - xQueueSend

Tags: task, freertos

A little question about the freeRTOS task scheduler:

Is the task scheduler called inside the xQueueSend function or is it call at the next system tick?

Comment: I hate answering the same question in multiple places so will just post a link to my previous answer https://sourceforge.net/p/freertos/discussion/382005/thread/f0cb1a73/ (which will also appear in the [support forum archive](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/freertos_support_forum_archive_index.html) at the end of the week).

Answer (score 0):

FreeRTOS will always run the highest priority task that is able to run.  That means if you use a queue, semaphore, direct to task notification, event group, mutex, (anything else?), in such a way that another task unblocks, and the task that was unblocked has a priority higher than the running task, then the scheduler will switch to the unblocked task.  The exception to that is if the application writer has locked the scheduler by calling [vTaskSuspendAll()](http://www.freertos.org/a00134.html), in which case the unblocked task will be held pending until such time that the application writer calls xTaskResumeAll() - in which case the highest priority task that is able to run will start to run immediately (before the call to xTaskResumeAll() returns even).